# Flutter iOS add2pp model PlatformChannel config

Tags: swift, flutter

I was confused by this problem for weeks.
I according to the [instruction-Add Flutter to existing apps](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Add-Flutter-to-existing-apps),everything is good running when i run the code in Android.
But when i run the code in iOS,it show all kinds of problem like 'EXC_BAD_ACCESS' and 'SIGABRT'.

Because i am Android developer and i am new to iOS,i don't know how to resolve this problem although i searched everywhere...

### AppDelegate.swift

```swift
import UIKit
import Flutter
import FlutterPluginRegistrant // Only if you have Flutter Plugins.


@UIApplicationMain
@objc class AppDelegate: FlutterAppDelegate {

    var flutterEngine : FlutterEngine?;

    override func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        self.flutterEngine = FlutterEngine(name: "io.flutter", project: nil);
//                methodOne(self);
                methodTwo();
//                methodThree();
//                methodFour();
        GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register(with: self.flutterEngine);
        return super.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions);
    }

    //Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x0)
    func methodOne(_ registry:FlutterPluginRegistry){
        SwiftPluginHelloPlugin.register(registry);
    }

    //Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x0)
    func methodTwo(){
        let registrar = self.registrar(forPlugin: "SwiftPluginHelloPlugin")
        let channel = FlutterMethodChannel(name: "plugin_hello", binaryMessenger: registrar.messenger())
        let instance = SwiftPluginHelloPlugin()
        registrar.addMethodCallDelegate(instance, channel: channel)
    }

    //Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x5a0)
    func methodThree(){
        let channel = FlutterMethodChannel(name: "plugin_hello", binaryMessenger: flutterEngine as! FlutterBinaryMessenger)
        channel.setMethodCallHandler({(call: FlutterMethodCall, result: @escaping FlutterResult) -> Void in
            result("iOS " + UIDevice.current.systemVersion)
        })
    }

    //Thread 1: signal SIGABRT
    func methodFour(){
        let controller : FlutterViewController = window?.rootViewController as! FlutterViewController
        let channel = FlutterMethodChannel(name: "plugin_hello",binaryMessenger: controller.binaryMessenger)
        channel.setMethodCallHandler({(call: FlutterMethodCall, result: @escaping FlutterResult) -> Void in
            result("iOS " + UIDevice.current.systemVersion)
        })
    }

}
```

---

SwiftPluginHelloPlugin.swift

```swift
import Flutter
import UIKit

public class SwiftPluginHelloPlugin: NSObject, FlutterPlugin {

    public static func register(_ registry:FlutterPluginRegistry){
        let registrar = registry.registrar(forPlugin: "SwiftPluginHelloPlugin")
        register(with:registrar)
    }

    public static func register(with registrar: FlutterPluginRegistrar) {
        let channel = FlutterMethodChannel(name: "plugin_hello", binaryMessenger: registrar.messenger())
        let instance = SwiftPluginHelloPlugin()
        registrar.addMethodCallDelegate(instance, channel: channel)
    }

    public func handle(_ call: FlutterMethodCall, result: @escaping FlutterResult) {
        result("iOS " + UIDevice.current.systemVersion)
    }
}
```

Another strange thing is when i setting up "Xcode-scheme-zombie objects" and "Xcode-scheme-Address Sanitizer" ,it didn't show the exception.
But when i invoke the platform channel,it shows below message

```
2019-09-05 16:49:45.947832+0800 WqzIOSBestPractice[71816:6385841] [VERBOSE-2:ui_dart_state.cc(148)] Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method getPlatformVersion on channel plugin_hello)
#0      MethodChannel.invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:319:7)
<asynchronous suspension>
#1      PluginHello.platformVersion (package:wqz_flutter_add2app_best_practice/plugin//plugin_hello.dart:10:43)
<asynchronous suspension>
#2      MyScaffoldBody._asyncInvoke (package:wqz_flutter_add2app_best_practice/plugin/PluginHelloApp.dart:92:43)
<asynchronous suspension>
#3      MyScaffoldBody.build.<anonymous closure> (package:wqz_flutter_add2app_best_practice/plugin/PluginHelloApp.dart:71:28)
#4      _InkResponseState._handleTap (package:flutter/src/material/ink_well.dart:635:14)
#5      _InkResponseState.build.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/material/ink_well.dart:710:32)
#6      GestureRecognizer.invokeCallback (package:flutter/src/gestures/recognizer.dart:182:24)
#7      TapGestureRecognizer._checkUp (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:365:11)
#8      TapGestureRecognizer.handlePrimaryPointer (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:275:7)
#9      PrimaryPointerGestureRecognizer.handleEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/recognizer.dart:467:9)
#10     PointerRouter._dispatch (package:flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart:75:13)
#11     PointerRouter.route (package:flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart:102:11)
#12     GestureBinding.handleEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:218:19)
#13     GestureBinding.dispatchEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:198:22)
#14     GestureBinding._handlePointerEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:156:7)
#15     GestureBinding._flushPointerEventQueue (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:102:7)
#16     GestureBinding._handlePointerDataPacket (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:86:7)
#17     _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1136:13)
#18     _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1029:19)
#19     _CustomZone.runUnaryGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:931:7)
#20     _invoke1 (dart:ui/hooks.dart:263:10)
#21     _dispatchPointerDataPacket (dart:ui/hooks.dart:172:5)
```